# Cloudfront Error: 502 ERROR The request could not be satisfied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have an aws lightsail instance. I have already created a distribution and choose the instance as my origin. But when I access the default domain that the distribution gives me: `xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net`, I got this message:

```
502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

But when I using my domain name to access, it works fine, except some request I got `x-cache: Miss from cloudfront`

In my distribution, I set up **Your distribution pulls content from your origin using HTTPS only**.

And in my WordPress's config, I already have my SSL certificate installed and config https like this:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

I don't know if there is anything wrong with my site, can you help me?

Comment: So the website works in HTTPS without using CloudFront? What kind of ssl cert did you use?

Comment: @Marcin I used bncert-tool to generate the certificate **Let's Encrypt**. When I check in chrome browser, it shows `Issued by: Amazon`

Comment: The two certificates are different (Let's encrypt vs Amazon) because they are for different connections. The Let's encrypt cert is used between wordpress <-> cloudfront, and the Amazon issued is used between cloudfront <-> browser.

Comment: Facing a similar problem with the CloudFront not reaching the load-balancer. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I just don't know what wrong with the **distribution**, **certificates** built-in **AWS Lightsail**.
So I go to service **AWS Cloudfront** and create a distribution with a certificate and config my Lightsail's DNS to this distribution. And everything works fine.
Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deploying-a-highly-available-wordpress-site-on-amazon-lightsail-part-1-implementing-a-highly-available-lightsail-database-with-wordpress/